# Applescript result of tell as argouments

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "Safari" to set the content of var1 to URL of active tab of front window
do shell script "grep " & var1 & "path-to-my-file/file"
```

If the url of active tab on Safari is  https://apple.stackexchange.com/
the applescript simulate the following command:

grep https://apple.stackexchange.com/     ....../file

I want to do that without store the result of " tell application safari " into a variable.
I try this but doesn't work

```
do shell script "grep " & tell application "Safari" to return URL of ....... & "...../file"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your first line of *code* `tell application "Safari" to set the content of var1 to URL of active tab of front window` doesn't even compile! It errors out with "**Syntax Error** A class name can’t go after this identifier." pointing to `active tab`. So, `do shell script "grep " & var1 & "path-to-my-file/file"` could't possibly work as written anyway!

A proper way to get the `URL` would be:

```
tell application "Safari" to get the URL of current tab of window 1 of application "Safari"
```

Or to set it to a *variable*, use:

```
tell application "Safari" to set theURL to (get the URL of current tab of window 1 of application "Safari")
```

So, the first two lines of *code* in your question would work if used like:

```
try
    tell application "Safari" to set theURL to (get the URL of current tab of window 1 of application "Safari")
    do shell script "grep " & quoted form of theURL & " /path/to/target/file"
end try
```

- Note there is a space after the double-quote before `/path/to/target/file` and this *space* is necessary.
- Also the *code* is wrapped in a `try` *statement* to trap any errors. Although you'd need to add additional *code* to process the *error(s)* accordingly using an `on error` *handler*. While the `try` *statement* will hide an *error*, using it in conjunction with an `on error` *handler* will be necessary if `grep` doesn't find a match and you want to do additional processing based on the results from the `grep` *command* not finding a match.

**If you really want to do it without setting the `URL` to a *variable*, then use this method:**

```
try
    do shell script "grep $(osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\" to get the URL of current tab of window 1 of application \"Safari\"')" & " /path/to/target/file"
end try
```

Note that in this case the necessary *space* can be as shown, after the double-quote before the *pathname*, or it can be placed after the closing parentheses of `$(...)` and before the closing double-quote prior to the ampersand, e.g: `...\"Safari\"') " &`